# Fetch PHAssets in sequence

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I am trying to fetch assets from photo library by passing an array of local identifiers. But the output is not in the same sequence. My app has a requirement that I fetch them in sequence.This is how I am using it

```
let fetchedResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: videosInLibrary, options: nil)
fetchedResults.enumerateObjects { (asset:PHAsset , count:Int, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
```

Is there anything we can do to fetch them in sequence of the local identifiers I passed.

Comment: Why don't you just accumulate all the resulting PHAssets into an array and then put it into whatever order you prefer?

Comment: I ended up doing the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is database, so returned as stored, but you can do it locally:

```
let fetchedResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: videosInLibrary, options: nil)

var tmpCache = [String: PHAsset]()
fetchedResults.enumerateObjects { (asset:PHAsset , count:Int, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
    tmpCache[asset.localIdentifier] = asset
}

let results = videosInLibrary.compactMap { tmpCache[$0] }
```